# Using Xbox Kinect v1 in ROS2 Humble for Autonomous Navigation

Tags: ros2, kinect, 3d-navigation, rgbd-slam

I have a question regarding the compatibility of the Xbox Kinect v1 with ROS2 Humble for autonomous navigation purposes. I have been researching online and found that there are drivers and packages available for ROS1, such as libfreenect, to work with the Xbox Kinect v1. However, my goal is to use this camera for autonomous navigation, SLAM, and nav2 in ROS2. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this in ROS2.

If anyone has experience or insights on using the Xbox Kinect v1 with ROS2 Humble and can provide guidance on the compatibility and data transfer between ROS versions, I would greatly appreciate your input. Additionally, if there are specific drivers or packages that I should be considering for this setup in ROS2, please feel free to share your recommendations.